# ie9 svg gradient not working

Tags: html, css

I used the Microsoft [gradient generator](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/SVGGradientBackgroundMaker/Default.html) to generate the following:

```
div.footer
{
    background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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); 
}
```

When I check the DOM it seems like it worked but I don't see any gradient on the page. Am I supposed to set something else?

Comment: Hmm.. my first thought was 'does the browser support that', but checking browser support for SVG backgrounds, and for data URLs, it *looks* like you should be okay in IE9. So not sure why it wouldn't be working.

Comment: here's a thought -- have you checked that the browser isn't going into IE8 or IE7 compatibility mode?

Answer (score 1):

What about your DocType? Have you declared your web page as HTML5 / SVG?